# Does a virtual machine realise that it is virtual?

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, vmware

I know that from a design point of view, the idea of a virtual machine is that the entire system environment is replicated so that the virtual machine is in outward appearance a full machine, but my question is about practical implementations. Do the virtual machines we use today have the ability to realise they are virtual machines?

Comment: What? Is it virtually intelligent?

Comment: You might be asking the wrong question. Why would a VM want to know if it's virtualized? Are you talking about the programming side of things? Or whether you can – in theory – make a VM aware of its virtualization?

Comment: According to Sarah  Connor, they did on August 29th 1997 at 2:14 AM

Comment: I'm not sure if it would ever have a need to know if it's virtualized or not. Maybe it could run differently to optimise speed while running in a virtual state, but I don't know and that isn't what I intended to find out :)

I wasn't asking in theory, so I guess it tends more towards programming side, but in any case my main emphasis was just whether practically a VM _can_ know if it is a VM.

Comment: Voted to close because the question makes no sense as it stands.  Our machines and programs aren't self-aware yet, so they don't "know" if they are anything at all.  Whether a program running on a particular virtual machine can detect whether the platform it's running on is virtual or not would be a more interesting and germane question for this site.

Comment: What's not to understand? Can an OS running on virtual platform have knowledge that it is running on this, or does it for all intents and purposes see a real system. It's really not a hard concept or question, and I don't see why a couple of people are picking up concepts of "self-awareness"...

Comment: Don't get me wrong, but people are picking up "self-awareness" because you are literally asking if the virtual machines *per se* are aware of the fact that they are VMs. Maybe it's also a language problem. Your question also doesn't seem to be based on an actual problem you're facing.

Comment: Yeah, I can see that. Before asking this question I wasn't sure on what exact type of question I could ask on this site, but now I realise it is problem-based questions, and general computing questions aren't really suitable. Oh well, live and learn.

Comment: Don't let that discourage you! We *do* encourage questions that ask for explanation (see our [FAQ]), but they should probably focus on a very narrow technical aspect. For example, if you were a programmer, how *you* (not the VM) could find out that you're working in a virtualized environment. Although programming questions are mostly off topic for us…

Comment: While I did VTC, you bring up an important point: NO THEY DO NOT. Virtual machines should be treated like physical machines. Being a VM changes a lot less than you might think. A lot of people new to VMs think the fact it's a VM is relevant to diagnostics. It's probably not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In theory, no.

Virtual machines are meant to be totally sandboxed and separated from the computer it runs within.

However, it is sometimes possible to abuse discontinuities in the virtual machine software itself to determine if a machine is running in a sandbox, [as illustrated here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9823/Detect-if-your-program-is-running-inside-a-Virtual) (this is more programming related, but shows what I mean).

Comment: +1 Excellent answer.  Great link to an interesting article explaining how VMs commmunicate with the host and how that can be detected.

Answer (score 1):

I know this question will get closed, but Ill throw my 2 cents in.

Many virtual machine hosts present different BIOSs and provide drivers for different OS types.  You could check for the existence of the BIOS and drivers and if they are in use.

However, you *could* fake their existence to give a false positive...

Comment: Cheers man! Could you tell me why you expect this to be closed though? I'm not sure what criteria the question is not meeting :)

Comment: It was a poorly written question.  I took a stab as to what I think you were trying to ask.  Even so, the question and answer isnt constructive.  Although the answer is correct in some cases, its possible it might not stay correct.

Comment: Hmm, I see. I'll try write questions with more clarity and purpose in the future. Ta mate!